# Realm subquery with count

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

People and groups. How many people are in each group? A simple scenario for an SQL database. Please help fetching this in Realm.

I have **People**:

```
@interface PersonObject : RLMObject

@property int idx;

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;

@property RLMArray <PersonGroupId *> <PersonGroupId> *connectedGroupIds;
```

And **Groups**:

```
@interface GroupObject : RLMObject

@property int idx;
@property NSString *name;
```

I need to get a list of all groups with a total number of people in each of them. Currently it's done by looping through groups and it's really slow:

```
for (GroupObject *group in groups)
    {
        RLMResults *result = [PersonObject objectsWhere:@"ANY connectedGroupIds.idx == %d",group.idx];
        group.numberOfMembers = result.count;
    }
```

Is it possible to fetch that with just one query/subquery without looping through groups?

Comment: Can you please share the declaration of the `PersonGroupId` class referred to in your code?

Comment: @bdash
`@interface PersonGroupId : RLMObject

@property int idx;

@end`

Comment: @bdash Would it be possible to fetch what I need with one query in the current model?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to model a scenario where a person can belong to multiple groups, and a group can contain multiple people. To do that I'd suggest a model that looks like:

```
@interface PersonObject : RLMObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;

@property RLMArray<GroupObject> *connectedGroups;

@end


@interface GroupObject : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;

@property RLMLinkingObjects<PersonObject> *members;

@end


@implementation GroupObject

+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties
{
    return @{ @"members": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:PersonObject.class propertyName:@"connectedGroups"] };
}

@end
```

This takes advantages of Realm's built in support for relationships rather than trying to mimic them using per-object identifiers. This model would allow you to determine the number of members in a group using `group.members.count`.

Comment: Yes, it's a many to many relationship. I need to maintain IDs of objects in any case since data model in Realm is a local storage for data that is stored in MySQL on the server. But I guess I can keep IDs and still use your suggested approach, right? I'm new to Realm. Sorry for dumb questions. How is the connection between a particular Person and a particular Group made when using LinkingObjects approach?

Comment: Yes, you can still store the IDs when using this approach. I just omitted them as they're no longer relevant to solving the problem. `LinkingObjects` is a collection that represents the objects that have a relationship with the object (in your case, that have group in the person's `connectedGroups` array). When you do `[somePerson.connectedGroups addObject:someGroup]`, `someGroup.members` will now contain `somePerson`.

Comment: Currently when I get people and groups from the server I just put them into Realm and don't care about connecting them to each other since I link them by ids when fetching. With this approach I will always have to remember to make/update the connection when I get/delete/edit people and groups, right? Also, I have another case where I have to also store dates when a person joined/left a particular group. How would that fit into the `LinkingObjects` approach? Where do I store this data?

Comment: Joining objects based on IDs is much less efficient than traversing one of Realm's native relationships. Yes, it means you'll need to establish the relationship at the time you insert the objects. But that's typically a much less frequent occurrence than reading the data, so it's a worthwhile tradeoff. If you need to store state on the many-to-many relationship itself, you can break it down into two one-to-many relationships (e.g., Person <-> GroupMembership <-> Group, with GroupMembership containing the extra fields).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips! Two last questions. 1) Did I get you right that with my current model it's absolutely impossible to fetch all groups with total amount of people in each with anything faster than looping?  2) In the model you suggested (Person <-> GroupMembership <-> Group) how do I get a list of groups with the total amount of people that have active membership ("joined" < current time, "left" empty or > current time) in each group?

Comment: 1) You could compute the same results more efficiently than your posted code by performing a single query for all people associated with the groups of interest, rather than performing one query per group. It'll still be significantly worse in terms of efficiency than using Realm's built-in relationships.

Comment: 2) `[group.members objectsWhere:@"joinDate >= %@ AND (partDate = nil OR partDate > %@)", someDate].count`. You could add a `activeMembersAtDate:` helper method on your `GroupObject` class to encapsulate the filtering portion of that logic.